# Rails / ActiveRecord API - include nested association in join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have models like this:

```
class User
  has_many :invites
  has_many :follows
  has_many :received_follows, class_name: 'Follow', inverse_of: :recipient

class Invite
  belongs_to :user

class Follow
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
```

A user can be invited to many events.  Also, users can follow other users in a one-way connection.

I am accessing the controller method `invites#index` to pull in a list of invites for a given user.  The Invite object itself isn't particularly useful, so in the response I want to include both the associated User object and, if applicable, the nested Follow object if the user making the request is following that user - this will save a ton of follow-up API calls.  Something like this:

```
invite: {
  id: 1,
  user: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Foo Bar',
    follow: {
      id: 1
    }
  }
}
```

To do that, I've done a `left join` on the follows table like this:

```
invites = @user.invites.
  joins(:user).
  joins("LEFT JOIN follows ON recipient_id=users.id AND user_id=#{current_user.id}")
```

That gets me the data that I want, but I'm not sure how to work the activerecord magic to package it up for the responder.  I've tried this, but it won't work for obvious reasons:

```
respond_with invites.to_json(include: [user: [:follow]])
```

Any help?  Am I going about this totally wrong?

Comment: Can you try `invites.to_json(include: { user: { include: :follows } })`

Comment: That will include the array of follows belonging to that user, not the single follow that I'm producing with the left join